# Django admin not showing models

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm damned if I can figure out why my models are not showing in the admin.

models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.title)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from publications.models import Publication

admin.site.register(Publication)
```

settings.py

```
...

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'django.core.context_processors.request',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)    


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'south',
    'publications',
)
```

Directory structure:

```
xrdb/
├── manage.py
├── publications
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── xrdb
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

And from the admin page, I can see Groups, Users, and Sites. No Publications!!

Any help??
Thanks!!

EDIT: I've already synced and migrated and admin.autodiscover() is in urls.py.

EDIT II: Updated files above. Added directory structure.

Comment: Run syncdb and then restart with `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Yes, yes. Already did all that. And schemamigration and migrate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you run syncdb after changing your models.py file?

Go to the base directory of your project (where manage.py is) and run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Edit: Since you already tried this, add a str or unicode method to your class like this:

```
class Resource(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)

    def __str__(self): # __str__ for Python 3, __unicode__ for Python 2
        return self.name
```

Edit 2: Funnily enough, I ran into the exact same issue today working on my own projects. If the **str** code above still doesn't work for you, double check that you've actually registered your models in admin.py:

```
from MyApp.models import MyModel
admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

Edit 3: Finally, make sure your admin.py file with the above code is actually inside the directory of the app in question (i.e. the same directory with your models.py that defines MyModel).

Comment: If you open your DB and look inside, do you see a table in there for Resource, or no?

Comment: @RobL Try adding a __str__ (if using Python 3) or __unicode__ (if using Python 2) method to your model class -- put two underscores on either side (I can't because formatting automatically italicizes it in this comment). Edited answer above to include. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-methods

Comment: Oooh, `__unicode__(self)`.  I'll try that when I get home. Maybe that's it. I'm in the mountains with my sweetie this weekend. I'll give it a go Monday morning. BTW, yes, the Table is in the DB.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'll work for you -- remember to come back to let us know how it worked out!

Comment: That's not it...`:-(`. I even tried renaming the app and model to publications/publication (thinking 'resource' was a reserved word, maybe). It shows up in the database. But not in the admin. WTF????

Comment: @RobL When you originally created the model, you used "manage.py startapp appname?" You have (2 underscores)init(2 underscores).py and a (2 underscores)pycache(2 underscores) folder in the app folder? Just trying to get everything narrowed down here.

Comment: @RobL Yeah sorry, just double checked that. See my edited comment above. Might be good to see a dump of your directory structure (or at least which subfolders the files you linked above are coming from). Also, please update your code above with the (2 underscores)str/unicode(2 underscores) bit as it's implemented.

Comment: Code updated in the original post. Directory structure added.

Comment: This may be a clue: `admin.pyc` is not being created.

Comment: @RobL Aha, I think I have it! Your admin.py you mentioned in your post needs to be in the publications directory!

Comment: Why yes, it does. Why don't you post that as an answer and I'll accept it. And THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @RobL Done, glad we were able to hammer it out!

Comment: hah, edit3 did the job for me :D what a silly mistake... thanks @GravityGrave

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you are calling:

`admin.site.register(<model-name>)`

and not

`admin.register(<model-name>)`

This was the cause for me.

Comment: Brilliant. Should probably be the first thing you check when you come across this problem.

Comment: Thankyou, another Django problem where no error is raised and nothing happens ^^.

Comment: Thnx a lot!
You saved my time for debugging an issue, I wish I'd found you at the first time!

Answer (score 10):

Double check your permissions - that is: if you think your user is a superuser, just go look to make sure!  If your user is not a superuser, look in your "Authentication and Authorization" › "Users" under the user you are logged in as and see if the "User permissions:" include the models for the application in question.

After chasing this for longer than I care to admit, I realized my user was not actually a superuser.  As you will see on many of the related posts, it is easy for an application to not show in Admin if the user does not have the correct permissions, such as here:
[image]

As you can see from this, user 2 does not have the required permissions on the "done" app's models - only on the "timekeeping" app's models.

I was fairly certain this was a superuser (but it's not).  I figure either I must have reduced my permissions to troubleshoot an issue another user had been seeing or to give a more representative experience using the system.

PS A giveaway for this being the issue is that any clean database where you use the `python manage.py createsuperuser` to get going will show all of your registered apps/models whereas an existing database (where permissions may be more nuanced) will show only some of your registered apps/models.

Comment: This was not the solution in my case. But I suppose it may be for others.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have admin.autodiscover() in urls.py.

Comment: I do have admin.autodiscover() in urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to my case, it may not be the same as yours.

Check if you have `admin.pyc` being created, if it is not being created then it is not being called. If it is not being called then one of the cause is you have `xrdb/xrdb/admin` folder with `__init__.py` in it.

I guess there can be other ways to do this but for me I created a file that would look to your case as `publications_admin.py` inside `xrdb/xrdb/admin` and add `import xrdb.admin.publications_admin` inside `xrdb/xrdb/admin/__init__.py`.

Do the registration inside `publications_admin.py`, that would look something like.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from xrdb.models import Publications

admin.site.register(Publications)
```

I hope it helps.
Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Delete all the migrations from migrations folder.

step 2: Go to root directory and type

```
python manage.py makemigrations publications
```

Note: publications here is your sub-app name

xrdb # Main directory folder

├── xrdb # Main app

├── publications # Sub app

step 3:

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate publications 0001
```

Note : 0001 is migrations file name

This will solve your problem

Cheers!!